# R: Add new column to dataframe using function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `df` that has two columns, **term** and **frequency**. I also have a list of terms with given IDs stored in a vector called `indices`. To illustrate these two info, I have the following:

```
> head(indices)
   Term
1    hello
256  i
33   the
```

Also, for the data frame.

```
> head(df)
   Term  Freq
1  i     24
2  hello 12
3  the   28
```

I want to add a column in `df` called `TermID` which will just be the index of the term in the vector `indices`. I have tried using `dplyr::mutate` but to no avail. Here is my code below

```
library(dplyr)

whichindex <- function(term){
              ind <- which(indices == as.character(term))
              ind}

mutate(df, TermID = whichindex(Term))
```

What I am getting as output is a `df` that has a new column called `TermID`, but all the values for `TermID` are the same.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? It would be nice as well if you can recommend a more efficient algorithm to do this in [R]. I have implemented this in Python and I have not encountered such issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `merge` (from base) or `join`?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of `dput(head(indices))` and `dput(head(df))` so that there is no ambiguity about what data structures you are working with.

Comment: Thanks, Ananda. I was actually looking for a faster algo since I am handling a few hundred thousand words. 

Both `df` and `indices` have `class = "data.frame"`. However, I noticed that each element of `indices` under the `Term` column is of `class = "factor"`.

Comment: `df$TermID <- match(df$Term,indices$Term)` will do it, and will take milliseconds on a million cases by my testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what about?

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(TermID = grep(Term,indices))
```

w/ example data:

```
library(dplyr)
indices <- c("hello","i","the")
df <- data_frame(Term = c("i","hello","the"), Freq = c(24,12,28))

df_res <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(TermID = grep(Term,indices))
df_res
```

gives:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

   Term Freq TermID
1     i   24      2
2 hello   12      1
3   the   28      3
```

Comment: I implemented the suggestion, and I didn't get any error. However, the resulting `df` remains unchanged (no additional `TermID` column). It must be because of the data structure. Let me check again to find some answers.

Comment: @EFL `df` remains unchanged you have to bind the output to a variable as in `df_res` in the above example. does this help answer your question? If not feel free to post your own answer and accept that otherwise.

Comment: What's the use of rowwise here? I tried without rowwise and it worked.