# Use variable name to define column contents with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame defined in this way:

```
dfB  <-  data.frame("_ID0" = c("z1", "z2", "z3"), check.names = FALSE)
```

I would like to add a column as shown below:

```
dfB %>% mutate(fk_table = "dfB")
```

**Instead of hard coding `"dfB"`, how can I calculate it dynamically?**

I've found an example here which calculates column names dynamically with `mutate` but doe not use the name of the variable passed.

[R: Add new column to dataframe using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838382/r-add-new-column-to-dataframe-using-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `substitute` inside a function

```
f1  <- function(dat) {
          name <- deparse(substitute(dat))
          #or
          #name <- as.character(match.call()[-1])

          dat %>%
               mutate(fk_table = name)
 }

f1(dfB)
#  _ID0 fk_table
#1   z1      dfB
#2   z2      dfB
#3   z3      dfB
```

Comment: This solution does exactly what I've asked for, but now I would like to use it inside a chain of `dplyr` commands. Is there a way to make this work? `dfB %>% f1()`

Comment: Thanks @agenis, that's exactly what I was testing while you were writing your comment!

Comment: Do I need to put everything inside `f1` and in that case always create a new temporary function whenever I want to make a change? Or is there another possibility? Maybe I should first add the necessary columns in base `R` before I start with the `dplyr` commands?

Comment: @Bobby I think you can use the function to create the variable and then use `%>%`  for any additional calculations.  I am not sure how to do that with `dfB %>% f1`